# Eclipse Java Project Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a new project in Eclipse called Lottery. The first thing that happened was I recieved a weird icon on my project that I never seen before.
[image]

I decided it was nothing and created a new class, called RandomNumberGenerator. Then it gave me the following error:

```
Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. 
Must define an explicit constructor
```

I have no idea what the problem is. Could somebody help? I can't create another class without an error!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be using an older version of eclipse, upgrading to Indigo could help you

Comment: I do not know. How do I figure it out.

Comment: Help -> About eclipse platform. Latest version is 3.7 , if you don't have that you should update.

Comment: Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2011.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this will help you

1. in project property dialog , check that JRE System Liabrary is set properly or not in     Java Build Path.
2. in same dialog check builders option , if you are using javascript code than this may be happed.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

Windows -> Show View -> Problems

You will have a detail of your project's errors. I would bet that is a **classpath** / **buildpath** / **JRE configuration** error.

Comment: Do you mean error log? Because that is all I can find in Windows-->Show View

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Problems

Answer (score 0):

i faced same problem when i am trying to create a simple helloword program in eclipse. it shows the "Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor" like these and any java package showing error.

Reason:
We are trying to access JRE 1.X version but that jre is not available on our system.
Example: we have installed jdk 7 but eclipse is trying to access JRE 8 system liberaries.

Solution:

Go to Eclipse-->Right click on project-->Java Build Path-->Liberaries-->Select JRE System Liberaries--> Remove
then add preferred JRE system liberaries:
Right click on project-->Java Build Path-->Libraries-->Select JRE System Liberaries--> Add Liberary-->JRE System Library-->Next-->Finish

I hope it will be helpful for that issue. I have also tried and resolved same.